# How do I replace only first instance of a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to replace the first instance of a word in a string with another string.  The problem is that the word being replaced sometimes appears more than once in the string that is being changed.  When that happens we only want the first instance to be replaced.  How can I do that?

Comment: regular expressions.

Comment: Look up IndexOf !

Comment: can you provide code with input string and expected output

Comment: Note: The question is unclear: Do you mean first instance of a string or of a word??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        string s1 = "something replace replace replace replace something";
        string s2 = "replace";
        string newString=s1;

        int index = s1.IndexOf(s2);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            newString = s1.Substring(0, index) + "newWord" + s1.Substring(index + s2.Length);
        }  
        Console.WriteLine(newString);
```